# Infinite for loop even though there's an ending statement

Tags: c, function, for-loop

I wrote a function to shift a substring to right when there's a capital letter, like

"AbCde" --> "Ab Cde"

But when I run it the for loop doesn't stop. Here's my code:

```
void MultipleNames(char name[]){

    int i, j, q = 0;
    for(i = 1; name[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if((int)name[i] >= 65 && (int)name[i] <= 90){
            for(j = strlen(name); j > i; j++)
                name[j] = name[j - 1];
            name[i] = ' ';
            i++;
            q++;
        }
}
```

And here's how i call it:

```
MultipleNames(alunni[i].nome);
```

Comment: `for(j = strlen(name); j > i; j++)` Please explain how this loop can possibly end.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. via undefined signed integer overflow, I presume?

Comment: Replace `65` with `'A'` and `90` with `'Z'`, and then replace all of that with `if(isupper(name[i]))`

Comment: And prefer `memmove` to hand-written loop.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Oops my bad. Thank you!

Comment: `name[j] = name[j - 1];` So you set `name[3]` to be the same as `name[2]`, and then you set `name[4]` to be the same as `name[3]`. See the problem? If you're going to copy in some direction to get the effect of a move, you have to start at the end, not the beginning.

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you! I tried with strcpy but didn't work, but with memmove it does

Comment: @JonathanFin yes, `strcpy` (as well as `memcpy`) will not handle overlapping regions (which you do have). `memmove` will.

Comment: In these situations you should make it as easy as possible for others to help you by posting a complete compilable example like:  https://onlinegdb.com/gZQN2GLef.  When executed there it does not enter an infinite loop, but it equally does not do what you intended.  You would also do well to debug code using a debugger before coming to SO - much more efficient.

Comment: ... actually it did not enter an infinite loop; it causes a seg-fault.

Comment: In general just don't type random code in some attempt to take a chance at how the language works through trial & error. You need to know what you are doing. `i = 1` is wrong. `(int)name[i]` is superfluous. Don't use magic numbers like 65, use 'A'. `j = strlen(name)` This is wrong, you start by accessing the array out of bounds. `i++;` in the inner loop doesn't make sense. And so on...

Comment: @Lundin `i = 1` I think is intentional because he does not want to insert a space before the initial capital.  A good argument for commenting your code though - to highlight non-idiomatic patterns that might accidentally get "fixed".  The `j = strlen(name)` causes the NUL terminator to be _correctly_ preserved.  Again it is non-idiomatic, so deserves a comment.  Who knows whether the array is accessed out-of-bounds - there is no bounds information or check - it is just dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
for( j = strlen(name); j > i; j++ )
```

You are starting from the *end* of the string and moving forward; `i > i` is always true, because it started thus and you increment `j` making the string ever longer and and adding the same character to the end each time. Instead:

```
for( j = strlen(name); j > i; j-- )
                               ^^
```

The issue is more easily discovers using a debugger (easier than posting questions on SO that is).  Another useful technique is to comment your code - explaining to yourself how it is expected to work is a good why of discovering why it does not. [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is a similar "verbal" approach.

The function can be simplified thus:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* MultipleNames( char name[] )
{
    size_t original_length = strlen( name ) + 1 ; // include NUL in length

    for( int i = 1; name[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if( isupper( name[i] ) )
        {
            memmove( &name[i + 1],             // Destination
                     &name[i],                 // Start 
                     original_length - i ) ;   // Length to end including NUL
            name[i] = ' ' ;                    // Insert space
            i++ ;                              // Advance past capital
        }
    }
    
    return name ;
}
```

Returning the `name` allows the function to be used as a string parameter thus:

```
char test[128] = "AbCde" ;
printf("%s", MultipleNames( test ) );
```

Comment: A mini-optimization is to call strlen once before the loop, then memmove `size-i` or such. And it would naturally be much more efficient to build up a new string instead, at the cost of more memory use.

Comment: @Lundin Good point.  I should have done that in the first place.  Will update shortly.